# Как получить табличную переменную по имени таблицы?

Tags: sql-server, функции, exec, cursor

У меня есть функция, которая должна пройтись по всем существующим временным таблицам, извлечь из них какие-то данные, вставить их в новую таблицу и вернуть ее как результат. Чтобы пройти по всем временным таблицам, я использую курсор. В цикле я планировал присваивать переменной запрос в текстовом виде, чтобы сообщить туда название таблицы, и выполнять его через exec.

Проблема в том, что в функциях нельзя выполнять команду exec.

Цикл **внутри функции**:

```
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
begin
    set @sql = N'
        insert into @temp (good, sold_price, auction, max_sold_price) 
        select distinct g.id, t.sold_price, g.auction, max(t.sold_price) over(partition by g.auction) 
        from ' + @tname + ' t join good g on t.good_id = g.id 
        where g.init_price > ' + (select convert(nvarchar(255), @iprice)) + ' 
        order by max_sold_price desc';
    exec(@sql);  -- ошибка
    fetch next from ttables_cursor into @tname;
end;
```

Можно ли получить таблицу (и записать ее в табличную переменную) по ее названию, чтобы я мог убрать эту строку и выполнить обычный запрос? Или, может быть, есть другие варианты решения проблемы?

Comment: Какая ошибка? Каким образом наполняется ttables_cursor? `order by max_sold_price desc` имеет смысл только если @temp содержит IDENTITY столбец

Comment: *может быть, есть другие варианты решения проблемы* - опишите исходную проблему, сейчас это очевидная XY-проблема. И да, динамический SQL нельзя выполнять в функции.